# Can't seem to figure out where this recursion is breaking

Tags: python, recursion

[This is for Advent of Code, Day 17.](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/15)
Basically, you have a map of "containers" and "water" that flows downward from y = 0. (Water pressure does not apply.) You're supposed to figure out how many grid cells will be "water" by the time it's done filling all the containers it can get to.

I literally got it ALMOST working in five minutes, but then it won't terminate ...
I've been messing with it for the good part of the day and still can't figure it out. Put print statements after every line to monitor what is happening (tried PythonTutor, but the way you have to scroll like five minutes to see the output, especially for long recursive code, after every iteration is a bit annoying).
Then tried shoving returns after nearly every line and inside every loop. Still nothing ...
I hate how simple recursion seems, but then you just start confusing yourself (at least I do...)
Now I'm just tired and confused.
Any help appreciated.

```
coor = [(495, 2), (495, 3), (495, 4), (495, 5), (495, 6), (495, 7), (495, 7), (496, 7), (497, 7), (498, 7), (499, 7), (500, 7), (501, 7), (501, 3), (501, 4), (501, 5), (501, 6), (501, 7), (498, 2), (498, 3), (498, 4), (506, 1), (506, 2), (498, 10), (498, 11), (498, 12), (498, 13), (504, 10), (504, 11), (504, 12), (504, 13), (498, 13), (499, 13), (500, 13), (501, 13), (502, 13), (503, 13), (504, 13)]

cx, cy = zip(*coor)
minx, maxx = min(cx), max(cx)
miny, maxy = min(cy), max(cy)

water = []

def flow(water, pt):
  if pt not in water:
    water.append(pt)
  x,y = pt
  if y < maxy:
    while (x, y+1) not in coor:
      if y+1 > maxy:
        return
      plotW(water)
      water.append((x,y+1))
      y += 1

    collect(water, (x, y))
  else:
    return


def collect(water, pt):
  x,y = pt
  if minx <= x <= maxx and y < maxy:
    i = x - 1
    j = x + 1

    # fills container half to the left of the stream
    while (i, y) not in coor:
      if y >= maxy: break
      plotW(water)
      if (i, y+1) in coor or (i, y+1) in water:
        if (i, y) not in water:
          water.append((i, y))
          i -= 1
      else:
        flow(water, (i, y))
        break

    # fills container half to the right of the stream
    while (j, y) not in coor:
      if y >= maxy: break
      plotW(water)
      if (j, y+1) in coor or (j, y+1) in water:
        if (j, y) not in water:
          water.append((j, y))
          j += 1
      else:
        flow(water, (j, y))
        break

    collect(water, (x, y-1))

def plotW(water):
  wx, wy = zip(*water)

  fig = plt.figure(figsize = (2,2.5))
  plt.xlim(minx-1, maxx+1)
  plt.ylim(miny-1, maxy)
  plt.scatter(cx, cy, marker = 's', color = 'r')
  plt.scatter(wx, wy)
  plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
  plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
  plt.show()

flow(water, (500, 0))
```

last couple steps look like this:
(should have stopped at the second image)
[image]

Comment: You need to explain what this code is supposed to do. When debugging, you could try using a smaller list of coordinates. Is it recursing infinitely? It looks like that would happen if `y` never reaches `maxy`.'

Comment: @Barmar, sorry, added a link and small description. It'll always reach maxy because the input is a list of 2d points for a 2d grid, so essentially the biggest y there is maxy

Comment: By Stack Overflow rules, each question should be self-contained. Supplementary links are welcome, but your question should not depend on them - some people don't want to risk going to potentially unsafe locations, sometimes links break and then the question gets stranded etc etc. It would be really great if you could copy the relevant parts of the link into the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> got it ALMOST working in five minutes, but then it won't terminate

I've modified it to terminate (at the stage you describe) through more strict monitoring of the `y` coordinate.  You'll have to decide if these changes make sense in the context of what you're doing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coordinates = [
    (495, 2), (495, 3), (495, 4), (495, 5), (495, 6), (495, 7), (495, 7), (496, 7),
    (497, 7), (498, 7), (499, 7), (500, 7), (501, 7), (501, 3), (501, 4), (501, 5),
    (501, 6), (501, 7), (498, 2), (498, 3), (498, 4), (506, 1), (506, 2), (498, 10),
    (498, 11), (498, 12), (498, 13), (504, 10), (504, 11), (504, 12), (504, 13),
    (498, 13), (499, 13), (500, 13), (501, 13), (502, 13), (503, 13), (504, 13)
]

cx, cy = zip(*coordinates)
min_x, max_x = min(cx), max(cx)
min_y, max_y = min(cy), max(cy)

water = []

def flow(water, point):
    if point not in water:
        water.append(point)
        plotW(water)

    x, y = point

    if y < max_y:
        while (x, y + 1) not in coordinates:
            if y + 1 > max_y:
                return y

            water.append((x, y + 1))
            plotW(water)
            y += 1

        y = collect(water, (x, y))

    return y

def collect(water, point):
    x, y = point

    if min_x <= x <= max_x and y < max_y:
        i, j = x - 1, x + 1

        # fills container half to the left of the stream
        while (i, y) not in coordinates:
            if y >= max_y:
                break

            plotW(water)

            if (i, y + 1) in coordinates or (i, y + 1) in water:
                if (i, y) not in water:
                    water.append((i, y))
                    i -= 1
            else:
                _ = flow(water, (i, y))
                break

        # fills container half to the right of the stream
        while (j, y) not in coordinates:
            if y >= max_y:
                break

            plotW(water)

            if (j, y + 1) in coordinates or (j, y + 1) in water:
                if (j, y) not in water:
                    water.append((j, y))
                    j += 1
            else:
                y = flow(water, (j, y))
                break

        if y < max_y:
            y = collect(water, (x, y-1))

    return y

def plotW(water):
    wx, wy = zip(*water)

    plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2.5))
    plt.xlim(min_x - 1, max_x + 1)
    plt.ylim(min_y - 1, max_y)
    plt.scatter(cx, cy, marker='s', color='r')
    plt.scatter(wx, wy)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
    plt.show()

flow(water, (500, 0))
```